# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while trying to scrape data from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some content from a website using the requests and BeautifulSoup modules. Here's the source code of the crawler that I wrote:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while(page <= max_pages):
        url = "https://buckysroom.org/trade/search.php?page=" + str(page)
        u = requests.get(url)
        src = u.text
        obj = BeautifulSoup(src)
        for a in obj.findAll("a", {'class' : 'item-name'}):
            title = a.string
            print(title)
        page += 1

trade(2)
```

However, I'm getting the following error every time I try to run this code:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What does this error signify and how can I resolve it ?

EDIT: Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python27/Web Scraping/buckyscrap.py", line 16, in <module>
    trade(2)
  File "E:/Python27/Web Scraping/buckyscrap.py", line 13, in trade
    print(title)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 74, in _reduce_ex
    getstate = self.__getstate__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What is the full traceback? Yes, that can be long, but please do include it anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Included the full traceback in the original post.

Comment: You hit a bug in IDLE, not with requests or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: See http://bugs.python.org/issue1757057